# How to use points defined in tkz-euclide in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Sometimes one would like to work with both tikz and tkz-euclide since some of them is more suitable for a specific purpose and vice-versa.

For example, consider the following simple example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0, 0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){B}
    \draw [black] (0,0) to (1,1) ;
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, I would like to use

```
\draw [black] A to B;
```

instead of

```
\draw [black] (0,0) to (1,1) ;
```

but it produces error. Is it achievable at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These points are called simply `A` and `B`, and therefore you can say `\draw (A) -- (B);`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0, 0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(1,1){B}
    \draw [black] (0,0) to (1,1) ;
\draw[red] (A) -- (B);  
%\tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```